# Aggregate logstash filter config

Tags: logstash

My goal is to combine events based on pId in logstash. But i find that events with same pId are not being combined into one event. I am not able to see any change after adding aggregation.Please help

Log looks like this:

```
June 1st 2017, 11:51:26.992 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:99 [DEBUG] - Received request:
June 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] - Id: abbababcajdfbjasndflsdlf
June 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] - unique id: AAAAA
June 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] Total time: 12
```

Here is my config:

```
filter {
grok{
match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp} %{DATA:id} %{DATA:pId} %{DATA:ClassName} [%{LOGLEVEL:severity}] - %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
}
if [message] =~ /Received request:/ {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{pId}"
code => "map['message'] = event['message']"
map_action => "create"
}
}
else if [message] =~ /Total time:^/ {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{pId}"
code => "map['new_message'] = event['message'];event['new_message'] = map['new_message']"
map_action => "update"
end_of_task => true
timeout => 120
}
}
else {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{pId}"
code => "map['new_message'] = event['message'];event['new_message'] = map['new_message']"
map_action => "update"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate is one of those filters that can be *really* hard to get right. In large part, because Logstash is designed from the bolts out to be parallel processing pipelines, each `aggregate` call in the filter stack is unique to the pipeline, and you can't be sure that all of the events will be run through the same pipeline. Out of the box, that is.

If you run logstash with the `-w 1` parameter to force everything through a single pipeline, you will get this behavior.

In this case, I recommend instead using the `multiline` codec on the `input` instead. This lumps all the loglines together in a single event that you can parse later in the filter stages. Of course, this assumes that each of these multiline events are dropped in at the same time and won't ever multiplex. If you get multiplexing, then aggregating is going to require losing your parallelism.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/app/debug_logs.log"
    codec => multiline {
       pattern => "Received request:"
       negate => true
       what => previous
    }
  }
}
```

This will search for events that *don't* match your `Received request:` regex and append them to the previous line. When it does see `Received request:` it will start a new event. Your `filter {}` stages will then see this

```
message => "June 1st 2017, 11:51:26.992 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:99 [DEBUG] - Received request:\nJune 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] - Id: abbababcajdfbjasndflsdlf\nJune 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] - unique id: AAAAA\nJune 1st 2017, 11:51:26.993 {id} {pId} ClassName:methodName:100 [DEBUG] Total time: 12"
```

Which is much easier to manipulate in a parallel context.

Comment: A sample config or documentation guiding how to do it using multiline can be helpful. I dont see stream_identity setting available in 5.4.

Comment: @user3141789 Gave you an example.

Comment: Thanks for you sample but there is a problem here. Here pId will be cluttered. I want to combine events only with same pId. Using above multiline config all the pIds will be combined.

Comment: @user3141789 If the log-lines arrive at the same time, this shouldn't be a problem. If they're arriving interleaved with other PID entries, then multiline is not your solution.